# how to get API name from permission service / request object spring?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, spring-security

We are working on API security in SPRING BOOT by using microservice architecture. Here we are using the APIs as rest microservice in which we have implemented custom PREAuthorize service.

```
@PreAuthorize("@permissionService.hasPermission()")
@RequestMapping(value="/getUser", produces="application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST , name="Get User")
```

Here we are going to validate API access by using the API names. Here when we try to get validate using the API path ex. /rest/api/getUser meansm, i can able to get from the request object.

```
@Service("permissionService")
public class PermissionValidator implements PermissionService{

    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = null;
    HttpServletRequest request = null;
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission() {
        boolean isAuthorized = false;
        requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
            request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
            System.out.println(request.getAttribute("name"));
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }
}
```

Problem:

We want to get the request mapping attribute API name which is name="Get User". Please help me to get it done.

Comment: The `name`-Field inside of `RequestMapping` isn't something you reference in a request to the endpoint. If you want to do an authorization based on the endpoint the user accessed I would add the name of the endpoint as a parameter to the `PreAuthorize` Annotation

Comment: `@PreAuthorize("@permissionService.hasPermission(\"getUser\")")` as the annotation and your method signature can look like `public boolean hasPermission(String calledMethod)`

Comment: @Fabian Thanks. It's working. Please help me in this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589951/how-to-authentication-and-authorization-using-jwt-in-sso-for-microservices